# Assign Value from Query with sum to Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to assign the value from a SQL Query to a text box.

I have the function tied to a ComboBox After update.

I tested the SQL by running it.

How do I assign the result to the Txtbox named prepoffEIC?

```vb
Dim MyVar2 As Integer
MyVar2 = Me.SelectedExam.Column(0)
ExamViewQry = "SELECT Sum(tblentrys.entryhours) AS TotalHoursPerFunction FROM tBleExams INNER JOIN (tBlBankList INNER JOIN (tBlExaminers INNER JOIN (tBlEntrys INNER JOIN tBlActivity ON tBlEntrys.EntryActivityID = tBlActivity.FunctionKey) ON tBlExaminers.ExaminersKey = tBlEntrys.EntryExaminerID) ON tBlBankList.BankID = tBlEntrys.EntryInstitutionID) ON (tBlBankList.BankID = tBleExams.ExamBankID) AND (tBleExams.ExamID = tBlEntrys.EntryExamID) WHERE tBlEntrys.EntryActivityID=1 AND tblEntrys.EntryExamStageID=1 AND tBleExams.ExamID=" & MyVar2

Me.prepoffEIC.ControlSource = "ExamViewQry"
Me.prepoffEIC.Requery
```

Comment: `ExamViewQry` is just a string.  I assume you need to execute this and return the result before you do anything else.

Comment: " I am trying to assign the value from a SQL Query to a text box and running into a road block." - what does it exactly mean? Do you want to create a list of values as a source of combobox/listbox? Or something else? Could you provide more details about this?

Comment: Do you want to assign a value, or a control source? If you assign a value, it will not auto-update with changing data, and you have to calculate the value in the VBA code and use the .Value property. If you want to assign a control source, you need to wrap the query in a `DLookUp` function.

Comment: the SQL returns a SUM, I want to assign that sum to the value of the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query using the sql you have, but slightly modded paste it here:
[image: Sql view]

```
PARAMETERS eid long;
SELECT Sum(tblentrys.entryhours) AS TotalHoursPerFunction
FROM tBleExams
INNER JOIN (
    tBlBankList INNER JOIN (
        tBlExaminers INNER JOIN (
            tBlEntrys INNER JOIN tBlActivity ON tBlEntrys.EntryActivityID = tBlActivity.FunctionKey
            ) ON tBlExaminers.ExaminersKey = tBlEntrys.EntryExaminerID
        ) ON tBlBankList.BankID = tBlEntrys.EntryInstitutionID
    ) ON (tBlBankList.BankID = tBleExams.ExamBankID)
    AND (tBleExams.ExamID = tBlEntrys.EntryExamID)
WHERE tBlEntrys.EntryActivityID = 1
    AND tblEntrys.EntryExamStageID = 1
    AND tBleExams.ExamID = [eid]
```

lets call it qryGetHours (since i dont know what you need it for.)
in the after update event (also use better naming, this is quick and dirty)

```
dim db as DAO.Database
dim qry as QueryDef
dim rs as DAO.Recordset

set db = currentdb
set qry = db.querydefs("qryGetHours")
'this is the name of the query you made above
qry.parameters("eid").value = me.SelectedExam.Column(0)
set rs = qry.openrecordset(dbopendynaset,dbseechanges)
'dbseechanges is more for if you have a sql server backend, but i usually do
if not ( rs.eof and rs.bof) then
    rs.movefirst
    me.prepoffEIC = rs.fields("TotalHoursPerFunction").value
    'This portion assumes that you only get one record back, 
    'or if you do end up with more than one, it only goes 
    'after the first one.
else
    msgbox "Errors... Errors everywhere."
    'You will definitely want to put something meaningful 
    'here relating to it not being able to find the data you 
    'were looking for.
end if
if not rs is nothing then
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
end if
set qry = nothing
set db = nothing
'you will always want to do this portion where you properly 
'check if a recordset exists and then close it when you are 
'done, along with closing out the querydef and database variables.
```

Comment: OK, As a VBA noob, I think I understand all of the second section. its the first code snippet, I am lost on. where the SQL code is.  thanks

Comment: On the ribbon you click create, then find Query Design. once you are in there, you will see a button on the far left, if you click the little down arrow under it, select the one that says SQL View.

Comment: Actually, i will add a picture to the post just to make it explicit.

Comment: Oh I see you mean having a Query Object in the DB. not just creating one on the fly! I get it.

Comment: Yea no problem, i used to do the on the fly querys, but i discovered it adds a LOT to database bloat (you know where it goes from a 3.5MB file to 700MB in a couple months of not compacting it)

Comment: and TADA... that did it... Thanks, I was hoping to be more dynamic (within the VBA code) with the querys but this will work. I will Adjust my thought process to work from this method....   Resistance is Futile!

Comment: and one quick last question. in the PARAMETERS eid LONG; (never seen this before) how would I go about adding 3 PARAMS. since I might use them for the other "AND" variables.

Comment: Yeah, i do this stuff day in day out, ive gotten to a point where i have an access file devoted to code modules i reuse the code from.

Comment: So, the parameters HAVE to be filled with something if they are listed in that section, but to add more, you would just do PARMETERS eid long, SecondParamter text(255); Also, you HAVE to have the semicolon between the parameters part and the rest of the query. EDIT: if you want to set the parameters, you can just goto the query tools when on the design grid view, and on the top it has a button called parameters. you can add to the list that way.

Comment: Beat ya to it... Thanks. Now I am going to play with using this bit of code over and over again for multiple text boxes.   Thanks again KySoto!

Comment: by the way, if you build a query that has ALL of the data that you need (for all of the fields you are working on) then you can use this method to load data into them all.

Comment: Thats exaclty what I was Thinking... Now contemplating how to write the SQL statement for ALL the totals with the all the variable... Might be a LONG SQL statement.....

Comment: By the way, would you mark my answer as the best answer if it was so?

Comment: Done! noob ... LOL